# Partial Rendering does not work when called from another method ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a function that does a partial render on my main page. The method works if called directly, from one of the links. The method is the following:

```
  def show_card
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|               
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I need to call this method from another method, or at least render the same thing this method renders, but with different parameters. My second method is this :

```
  def like_activity
    @user = current_user
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    @user.like_activity!(@activity)
    all = Activity.all
    notWanted = Activity.where(id: Activity.joins(:memberships).where({ "memberships.user_id" => current_user.id})).or(Activity.where(id: Activity.joins(:likes).where({"likes.user_id" => current_user.id}).where.not("likes.user_likes_activity" => nil)))
    queue = all - notWanted
    nextActivity = queue.first()
    redirect_to action: 'show_card', controller: 'pages', id:nextActivity.id
  end
```

Basically, after you like an activity, the method should call the show_card and display the new activity. However, I'm getting the following error:

> ActionController::UnknownFormat

While this is the output I get on the console :

```
> Redirected to http://localhost:3000/pages/show_card?id=88 Completed
> 302 Found in 99ms (ActiveRecord: 59.6ms)
> 
> 
> Started GET "/pages/show_card?id=88" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-01
> 17:12:35 -0800 Processing by PagesController#show_card as HTML  
> Parameters: {"id"=>"88"}   User Load (6.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM
> "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2 
> [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]   Activity Load (6.3ms)  SELECT 
> "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2
> [["id", 88], ["LIMIT", 1]] 
> Completed 401 Unauthorized in 23ms`
> (ActiveRecord: 12.8ms)
> 
> 
>    ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat): 
> app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:13:in `show_card'
```

I'm very confused on what am I missing. I'm also using Devise, I don't know if that might have to do with the 401 - Unauthorized. If you have any idea of what could be going on it would be really appreciated if you could let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: Although I still haven't figured it out, I believe the problem is that redirect_to is in HTML while the format is in js. That said, I still haven't figured out how to do the partial render in AJAX.

Comment: I think the issue is in the request format it should be as js to the controller action. Add remote: true, if you have not added in the form_for used in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is indeed a mismatch between the `request` type in ajax and the `controller respond_to`.

You can either ask for `text/html` and directly `render_to_string` on your `action` or, what I usually prefer doing, ask for `application/json`, and have a `respond_to` similar to this:

```
def some_ajax_action
  html = (render_to_string partial: 'some/partial/somewhere', locals: { something: @some_instance_variable_for_the_partial }, layout: false)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { string_partial: html, success: true } }
  end
end
```

Then just pick the `string_partial` element in the front end and replace it.